# getDisplayMedia split choice window on chrome

Tags: javascript, get-display-media

I noticed that [google hangout meets](https://meet.google.com) provide the functionality to select if you want to share an entire monitor, application, or just a browser tab and instead of one menu, it is split into three.
I tried applying constraints like `displaySurface: "monitor"`, but it didn't work and still provided all choices in one window. I was wondering how to achieve the same functionality in chrome as google hangouts, because according to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture)

> Note: Unlike most uses of constraints in media APIs, here it's solely used to define the stream configuration, and not to filter the available choices.

and this seems counterintuitive to the implementation that [meet.google.com](https://meet.google.com) have unless there is a way to achieve this without constraints

Comment: Interesting, they aren't using `getDisplayMedia` (tried to spoof it). They might have opened a backdoor only for their product, wouldn't be the first time. Note that in Firefox both buttons will do the same thing.

Comment: @Kaiido so it seems like a dead-end then. As for firefox, I noticed this too, but I assumed it's due to the fact  that getSettings method doesn't return information like displaySurface. While I understand that it is done for security reasons, that you can't limit choices, on chrome you can still check if the user isn't sharing an entire monitor and promt him/her to choose the entire screen, still it would cause less confusion and better user experience if you could do something like what's done in google meets.